# Concatenating Twilio Transcriptions to Display Complete Sentence in UI

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, twilio, twilio-api

I am working on a project using Twilio for call transcription in my application. I receive transcriptions in packages during the call, and I want to display the complete sentence in the frontend UI without repetition. Here's a simplified example of what I'm dealing with:

userSpeaks:"**hey i am foo bar and i am a software developer**"

The challenge I'm facing is that the  transcriptions are received incrementally, leading to repetition in the UI. For instance:

- "hey"
- "hey i"
- "hey i am"
- "hey i am foo"
- "hey i am foo bar"
- "and"
- "and i "
- "and i am"
- "and i am a"
- "and i am a software developer"

I want to display the entire sentence without repeating the text in the UI. For example, if the user says "Hey, I am Foo Bar, and I am a software developer," I want the UI to show exactly that.

**Question:**
How can I efficiently concatenate Twilio transcriptions during a call to display the complete sentence without repetition in the frontend UI? Are there any best practices or specific approaches I should consider for handling this scenario?

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the relevant part of my code:

```
 ws.on("message", function incoming(message) {
const msg = JSON.parse(message);
switch (msg.event) {
  case "connected":
    console.log(`A new call has connected.`);
    break;
  case "start":
    recognizeStream = client
      .streamingRecognize(request)
      .on("error", console.error)
      .on("data", data => {
    //here i get incremental transcript.
        console.log(data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript);
      });
    break;
  case "media":
    console.log(`Receiving Audio...`)
    break;
  case "stop":
    console.log(`Call Has Ended`);
    break;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may take the following actions to effectively concatenate Twilio transcriptions during a call and show the entire sentence in the frontend user interface (UI) without repetition:

1. Hold the transcriptions in `Buffer`
2. Identify sentence boundaries: To identify sentence boundaries in the concatenated text, use an algorithm or a `natural language processing (NLP)` package. This will make it easier to tell when someone has finished speaking a sentence.
3. Update UI with whole sentences

Follow these steps to implement

```js
let transcriptionBuffer = "";  // Buffer to store incremental transcriptions

ws.on("message", function incoming(message) {
  const msg = JSON.parse(message);

  switch (msg.event) {
    case "connected":
      console.log(`A new call has connected.`);
      break;

    case "start":
      transcriptionBuffer = "";  // Reset the buffer on the start of a new transcription
      recognizeStream = client
        .streamingRecognize(request)
        .on("error", console.error)
        .on("data", data => {
          const incrementalTranscription = data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;

          // Append the incremental transcription to the buffer
          transcriptionBuffer += incrementalTranscription;

          // Use NLP or a simple rule-based approach to detect sentence boundaries
          if (sentenceBoundaryDetected(incrementalTranscription)) {
            // Update UI with the complete sentence without repetition
            updateUI(transcriptionBuffer);

            // Reset the buffer for the next sentence
            transcriptionBuffer = "";
          }
        });
      break;

    case "media":
      console.log(`Receiving Audio...`);
      break;

    case "stop":
      console.log(`Call Has Ended`);
      break;
  }
});

function sentenceBoundaryDetected(incrementalTranscription) {
  // Implement a function to detect sentence boundaries based on your requirements
  // This could involve using an NLP library or simple rules (e.g., detecting punctuation marks)
  // Return true when a sentence boundary is detected
  // Example: return incrementalTranscription.endsWith(".");
}

function updateUI(sentence) {
  // Implement logic to update your frontend UI with the complete sentence
  console.log("Complete Sentence:", sentence);
  // Add your UI update logic here
}
```

The `sentenceBoundaryDetected` function should `return true` when a complete sentence boundary is detected but make sure to replace the placeholder functions `(sentenceBoundaryDetected and updateUI)` with your actual implementation based on the requirements of your application.

Comment: In the context of my real-time calling app, where timely responses are essential, I've noticed a lack of punctuation in the transcripts and the 'sequenceNumber' consistently being 1. Considering this, are there specific features or adjustments in Google Speech-to-Text that can help identify partial sentences versus complete sentences, without relying on the 'sequenceNumber' or punctuations?
for context actual response is like:
"give"
"give"
"give me "
"give me a"
"give me a phone"
"give me a phone"

Comment: Yeah, can without relying on the 'sequenceNumber' or punctuations. 

You can receive and process interim results in real time, improving the responsiveness of your calling app.

You have to use `https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-speech/` and then can enable the `enable_interim_results` option when making API requests.


Read this doc: `https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1`

Check the version which one you like: `https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/speech/latest`